# Paginate my Html / Php / MySql script

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

How can I paginate this script to show 5 rows on one page and 5 on another and so on. I have tried tutorials and more for this but still cant get it.

Following is my code :

```
<?php require "manybr.htm" ?>
<style>
<?php require "styles.css" ?>
</style>
<?php

$host="XXXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/view.png' width='50%' align='center'>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Group</th><th align='center'>Submition By</th><th align='center'>Submition On</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th     align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th><th align='center'>Vote</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><a href="http://aol.cellufun.com/p/grp/grp.asp?v=??&grp=<? echo $rows['group']; ?>">{<? echo $rows    ['group']; ?>}</a> </b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><a href="http://aol.cellufun.com/p/player.asp?v=&p=<? echo $rows['yname']; ?>"><? echo $rows['yname'];     ?><a> </b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['date']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>%     No</b></td>
<td background='transpatent' align='center'><b><a href='works.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img src='images/ThumbsUp.png' height='30'     width='30'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='dworks.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img src='images/ThumbsDown.png' height='30' width='30'></a>

</td> 
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
</table>
```

I have added `LIMIT 0 , 5` to my query and now 5 show up.  How do I do the part with links to page 2?

I don't know `MySqli` or `PDO` yet. I will learn soon so please don't make that comment. I will move my inline code into CSS soon but not yet.  I need to get this working first.

```
<?php

$host="XXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


// select record from mysql 
 $offset=$_GET['p'];
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT 4 OFFSET ".$offset;
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/subbg.png' width='70%' align='center'>
<tr><th><?php require "links.php" ?></th></tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Group</th><th align='center'>Submition By</th><th    align='center'>Submition On</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th   align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th><th   align='center'>Vote</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><a     href="http://aol.cellufun.com/p/player.asp?v=&p=<? echo $rows['yname']; ?>"><? echo   $rows['yname']; ?><a> </b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['date']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></td>
 <td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font    color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>% No</b></td>
<td background='transpatent' align='center'><b><a href='works.php?id=<? echo   $rows['id']; ?>'><img src='images/ThumbsUp.png' height='30' width='30'>  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='dworks.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img   src='images/ThumbsDown.png' height='30' width='30'></a>

</td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
    }
?>

</table>
```

^^^^ update above for bozdoz

Comment: please stop editing my Q

Comment: Collaborative editing is a feature.  Please review the site FAQ.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing -- please make an effort to use proper spelling, grammar, capitalization and punctuation, and you'll find others need to edit your posts less frequently.

Comment: You have to set a default $offset in that example.  You should also check that $_GET['p'] is set with if(isset($_GET['p'])&&is_int($_GET['p'])){ ... }

Comment: @Charles they were editing to make it shorter for what i needed i thank them but then people changed it back and forth

Comment: im completley new to php to be honest i have had this script for about 3 weeks and got it looking like i want and setup like i want im learning more from editing but right now i have no idea what u said :c

Comment: You can take a look at this sqlfiddle to see how LIMIT and OFFSET work:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92bcd/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `$_GET` variable to get the limit:

Make the URL something like `index.php?p=5` let's say.

The PHP can include the $_GET variable like this:

```
<?php

$startnum = 0; //set default
if(isset($_GET['p'])&&is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
  $startnum = $_GET['p'];
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT $startnum, 5";

?>
```

Next and previous links can be `<a href="?p=<?php echo $startnum+5 ?>">Next</a>`

### FULL PHP HERE:

```
<style>
<?php require "styles.css" ?>
</style>
<?php

$host="XXXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$startnum = 0; //set default
if(isset($_GET['p'])&&is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
  $startnum = $_GET['p']; //change offset
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT $startnum, 5";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>


See the <a href="?p=<?php echo $startnum+5; ?>">next page</a>
<table background='images/subbg.png' width='70%' align='center'>

<tr><th><?php require "links.php" ?></th></tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Group</th><th align='center'>Submition By</th><th    align='center'>Submition On</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th   align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th><th   align='center'>Vote</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><a     href="http://aol.cellufun.com/p/player.asp?v=&p=<? echo $rows['yname']; ?>"><? echo   $rows['yname']; ?><a> </b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['date']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></td>
 <td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font    color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>% No</b></td>
<td background='transpatent' align='center'><b><a href='works.php?id=<? echo   $rows['id']; ?>'><img src='images/ThumbsUp.png' height='30' width='30'>  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='dworks.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img   src='images/ThumbsDown.png' height='30' width='30'></a>

</td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
    }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: i replaced the old one with this one but the page still doesnt change the page url does but it shows same posts heres the code:   // select record from mysql 
$startnum = 0; //set default
if(isset($_GET['p'])&&is_int($_GET['p'])){
  $startnum = $_GET['p'];
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT $startnum, 5";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/subbg.png' width='70%' align='center'>
<tr>
<th><a href="?p=<?php echo $startnum+5 ?>">Next</a></th>

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code example contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string.  Please correct your example to remove the vulnerability.

Comment: Charles, what vulnerability?

Comment: @Charles, what vulnerability?

Comment: @user1837896 Could be right.  Congrats on finding a solution. :)

Comment: bozdoz im not really understanding how you want me to do it i have been working with what you have said and i cant figure it out can u edit my code and post in your answer please..

Comment: @user1837896 Is the limit working? Is it showing 5 entries?  Why don't you update your question with where you're at now?

Comment: @bozdoz, oh, I totally missed the `is_int` there.  I was expecting a cast, not a validation check.  Nevermind.  And dude, I'm not a bot.  \*beep\*

Comment: @bozdoz 


PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'a7972613'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a7972613/public_html/vp.htm on line 19

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a7972613/public_html/vp.htm on line 19

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a7972613/public_html/vp.htm on line 50  is what i got

Comment: Says access denied.  Sounds like there are more problems there.  Also, no password?

Comment: @bozdoz there is a password.. im not going to put connection info here but if you want you can email me its on my profile

Answer (score 3):

in your SQL Query append `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1` to display 5 results in page one.Increment the offset value for the next page .

Example :

`OFFSET 2` gives you the next 5 results and so on...

To put a link to the next page you can try setting the offset value as a variable.

`OFFSET $offset` where the `$offset` is incremented in php.

**index.php**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['p'])){
   if(is_numeric($_GET['p']))
      $offset=$_GET['p'];
   else 
      $offset=1;
  }
 else 
  $offset=1;

 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET ".$offset;
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Then for the link

```
<a href='index.php?p=2'>2</a>
```

That should display 2 page and so on you could do it

Comment: i added LIMIT 0 , 5 to it and it now shows 5 results now how do i do the link to show other 5 results?

Comment: // select record from mysql 
$offset=1;
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET ".$offset;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/subbg.png' width='70%' align='center'>
<tr>
<th><a href="?p=<?php echo $offset=-1 ?>">back</a> <a href="?p=<?php echo $offset=2 ?>">Next</a></th>

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a7972613/public_html/vp.htm on line 53
 after doing this to the script 
// select record from mysql 
$offset=$_GET['p'];
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET ".$offset;
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/subbg.png' width='70%' align='center'>
<tr>
<th><a href='index.php?p=2'>2</a></th>

Comment: i clicked on 2 and it loaded the page

Comment: ok so i changed the limit to 2 per page and changed it to p=1 and p=2 and p=3 it worked but if i just go to the url without ?p=1 it gives me that error also i have to manualy type it in the url it dosent make the links automaticly judging by how many rows and the limit

Comment: @MevinBabu **WARNING!** Your code example contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string.  Please correct your example to remove the vulnerability.

Comment: @Charles yes your right this code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

You can put LIMIT in your SQLQuerry

Comment: if i put a limit say 5 is it how would i include a link to the second page with 5 more ??

Comment: if i add SELECT * FROM `tylted` LIMIT 0, 5  to it how would i link the other pages??

Comment: Use a $_GET variable to get the page number from the URL. If the page is home.html?page=5 then the limit can be LIMIT $_GET['page'], 5 which is limit 5, start at the 5th row.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you can use the [`LIMIT offset, row_count` clause in MySQL to extract only a few rows at a time (or alternatively `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset`)](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).

And to get that offset, you can fetch a value from the URL that you could name `page`, and put that variable in the links to the next and previous pages.

E.g. Let us say that there are five items shown on the page. On the first page, fetch 5 rows, and the count of all items. If there are more items, add a link to `results.php?page=2`. From that variable, we know what our offset will be. Since that the offset for page one was (implicitly) zero, page two will be 5, and page three will be 10, we can extract a simple formula: `offset = ($_GET["page"]-1) * items_per_page`

There are a few more details to cover, such as empty result sets and whether the `page` variable is present or not, but I'll leave that up to you.

### Reference:

[MySQL ::   MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)